# mounting by default at startup with /etc/fstab doesn't work

Tags: mount, startup

I'm trying since a few hours to mount a partition (md0) automatically with the server start.

The Content of my /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdd1 during installation
UUID=369adef0-c8d7-4a35-9fcf-6e8cb6dc2546 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdd5 during installation
UUID=ed608f40-8f2f-4f57-8488-8981cc602010 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sde1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
/dev/md0        /mnt/RAID       ext4    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

But it doesn't work. Then I mount it manually via `mount -t ext4 /dev/md0 /mnt/RAID`, what works well. But it's very annoying to mount it manually every time the server has rebooted.

Is there a way to have this done automatically?

---

<sub>As it is easily confused: this is about **mounting by default at startup** of the system, but **not about automount**. The difference is that automounting mounts the filesystem automatically on access of actual files - physical read and writes - and usually unmounts when not in use.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `noauto` as one of the options for mounting `/dev/md0`. This means that the device will not be mounted implicitly (on boot, or by `mount -a`), but instead must be explicitly mounted.

Remove `noauto`, and you should get the behaviour you expect.

Comment: How embarrassing, but sometimes you don't see the easiest things on the first view. Anyway, thank you! It works now. :-)